# HTML form autofill right value

Tags: forms

I've got a HTML form:

```
<form>
          <input name="name" type="text" class="feedback-input" placeholder="Naam" />
          <input name="crebonummer" type="number" pattern="\d*" class="feedback-input" placeholder="Crebonummer" />
          <input type="text" name="Opleiding en niveau" class="feedback-input" id="autocomplete" placeholder="Opleiding en niveau">
          <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radios" class="feedback-input border-left" value="all" checked="">
          <label for="radio1" class="fl border-left">Leerweg BBL</label>
          <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radios" class="feedback-input border-right" value="false">
          <label for="radio2" class="border-right">Leerweg BOL</label>
          <input type="date" placeholder="Wanneer moet je stage lopen?" class="feedback-input">
</form>
```

When the second field ("Crebonummer") is completed with a number, I want the next field ("Opleiding en Niveau") automatically being filled with the linked information depending on that number.

For example: Number that filled in is 12345
The value that is linked to that number is: Test1234 and is automatically filled in the next field.

Is there any script doing that?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a scripting language which is Javascript. Use AJAX to retrieved data and parse then the result to that textbox. Try to refer to this link http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_first.

Comment: Thanks, but is there any ready-to-use script that already does what I want?

Comment: No I haven't yet! Is it possible to work only with javascript?

Comment: Then how we can check and retrieve the value of input if you doesn't have a database. Although it is possible to any storage like on the textfile. But i suggest you to have a database. I recommend you to use php to parse the JSON string and display to textfield.